# Fragment Crashes when changing navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation drawer where there are multiple options  such as Exhibition, Artist and Gallery. When I click an item in the content view in my Exhibition it works. Than if I try to navigate to other navigation drawer item such as Artist or Gallery after previewing the item in the individual fragment activity, the entire app crashes. Can anyone pls help??

**Code**..

```
private class LoadViewTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    Activity mContex;
    GridView listView;

    public LoadViewTask(Activity mContext, GridView grid_view) {
        .......
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        ....
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ...........

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        if(getActivity()!=null){
        loadListing();
        }

    }

    private void loadListing() {
        ChannelAppProductsArrayAdapter adapter = new ChannelAppProductsArrayAdapter(
                mContex, R.layout.itemlisting, productList, imageLoader);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //EDITED VERSION TO INITIATE SLIDER DRAWER
        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        //prevent user from manually opening the drawer
        mDrawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED); 
        //Allow ScrollView at the preview-layout
        ScrollView SV= (ScrollView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.scrollView_Preview_Layout);
        SV.scrollTo(0, 0);
        SV.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
        //END OF EDITED VERSION TO INITIATE SLIDER DRAWER

        //listView.setOnClickListener()


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                /*String text = "Item click... should be implemented @ position: "
                        + position;
                Toast.makeText(mContex, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
                Product product = productList.get(position);
                String productID = product.getId();


                String productDesc = product.getName();
                TextView ProductSummary;
                String productName=product.getDescription();
                TextView ProductName;
                ImageView productImage;
                imageLargename=productList.get(position).getLarge_image();

                //EDITED VERSION TO SHOW RIGHT DRAWER-18/11/2014
                mDrawerToggle = new CustomActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawer);
                mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
                mDrawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
                getActivity().getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true); // Prevents user from opening the drawer using the app icon

                Log.i("View onItemClick: ArtistProductDetailsFragment", "toggleRightDrawer()"+ productDesc);
                //END OF EDITED VERSION TO SHOW RIGHT DRAWER-18/11/2014

                //EDITED VERSION TO DISPLAY VIEW FOR SELECTED FRAGMENT ITEM-19/11/2014
                View RDrawerView = mDrawer.findViewById(R.id.preview_layout);

                //To set TextView of Product Name
                ProductSummary = (TextView) RDrawerView.findViewById(R.id.productsummary);
                ProductSummary.setText(productDesc);

                //To set TextView of product description
                ProductName= (TextView) RDrawerView.findViewById(R.id.productdesc);
                ProductName.setText(productName);

                //To get product Image from array
                productImage =(ImageView) RDrawerView.findViewById(R.id.productimage);
                String imgFilePath = url + imageLargename;
                imageLoader.displayImage(imgFilePath, productImage, options);


                productImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(mContex,
                                "Pinch & Zoom To See Large Photo.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        String imgFilePath = url + imageLargename;
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                mContex.getApplicationContext(),
                                FullScreenViewActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("path", imgFilePath);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                });
                //END OF EDITED VERSION TO DISPLAY VIEW FOR SELECTED FRAGMENT ITEM-19/11/2014

            }
        });

    }

    //EDITED VERSION FOR CUSTOMACTIONBARDRAWERTOGGLE
    private class CustomActionBarDrawerToggle extends ActionBarDrawerToggle {

        public CustomActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity mActivity,
                DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout) {
            super(mActivity, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer,
                    R.string.ns_menu_open, R.string.ns_menu_close);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(getActivity().getString(R.string.ns_menu_close));
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(getActivity().getString(R.string.ns_menu_open));
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    }
    //END OF EDITED VERSION FOR CUSTOMACTIONBARDRAWERTOGGLE

}
```

**Error Log**..

```
11-26 10:47:50.719: E/AndroidRuntime(19168): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-26 10:47:50.719: E/AndroidRuntime(19168): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 10:47:50.719: E/AndroidRuntime(19168):    at com.dapoaugury.channelappdemo.fragment.ChannelAppProductFragment$LoadViewTask$CustomActionBarDrawerToggle.onDrawerClosed(ChannelAppProductFragment.java:332)
11-26 10:47:50.719: E/AndroidRuntime(19168):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.dispatchOnDrawerClosed(DrawerLayout.java:477)
11-26 10:47:50.719: E/AndroidRuntime(19168):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.updateDrawerState(DrawerLayout.java:457)
11-26 10:47:50.719: E/AndroidRuntime(19168):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$ViewDragCallback.onViewDragStateChanged(DrawerLayout.java:1355)
11-26 10:47:50.719: E/AndroidRuntime(19168):    at android.support.v4.widget.ViewDragHelper.setDragState(ViewDragHelper.java:866)
11-26 10:47:50.719: E/AndroidRuntime(19168):    at android.support.v4.widget.ViewDragHelper$2.run(ViewDragHelper.java:335)
11-26 10:47:50.719: E/AndroidRuntime(19168):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
11-26 10:47:50.719: E/AndroidRuntime(19168):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-26 10:47:50.719: E/AndroidRuntime(19168):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-26 10:47:50.719: E/AndroidRuntime(19168):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
11-26 10:47:50.719: E/AndroidRuntime(19168):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 10:47:50.719: E/AndroidRuntime(19168):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-26 10:47:50.719: E/AndroidRuntime(19168):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-26 10:47:50.719: E/AndroidRuntime(19168):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-26 10:47:50.719: E/AndroidRuntime(19168):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT 1:

I have resolved my own issue. Thanks.

That is to totally remove the entire method for `private class CustomActionBarDrawerToggle extends ActionBarDrawerToggle`. I have realised that it is not applicable for the second drawer as it does not call on the action bar for any sliding drawer function.

Comment: Who called `loadListing()` method?

Comment: @Glenn in onPostExecute Method, I have updated the code

Comment: There are only two objects that are accessed in onDrawerClosed, that might be generating the NPE: the activity or its action bar. First figure out which is null, and then try to figure out why. If it's the activity, then maybe the activity was finished before the AsyncTask completed. Or if its the action bar, make sure you have it configured correctly (although it seems like you must, since you do refer to it before then.

Comment: @Bruce How would you suggest I figure which is actually null??Thanks

Comment: you can put break-point on that line inside onDrawerClosed method and check for the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is to totally remove the entire method for private class `CustomActionBarDrawerToggle extends ActionBarDrawerToggle`